# Python - Get max value in a list of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset with this structure :

```
In[17]: allIndices
Out[17]: 
[{0: 0, 1: 1.4589, 4: 2.4879},
{0: 1.4589, 1: 0, 2: 2.1547},
{1: 2.1547, 2: 0, 3: 4.2114},
{2: 4.2114, 3: 0},
{0: 2.4879, 4: 0}]
```

I'd like to identify the highest value inside the list of dict. I do as follow :

```
def findMax(data):

    possiblemax = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        temp = list(data[i].values())
        tempmax = max(temp)
        possiblemax.append(tempmax)

    maxValue = max(possiblemax)
    return maxValue
```

It works but I work with a very large dataset and it's a little bit slow. I was wondering of a better and faster way of doing this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Dunno if it is faster, but how about `def findMax(data): return max(max(d.values()) for d in data)
`

Comment: I'd also advice against using integers as dict keys, which also wouldn't work if you wanted to use the dict() constructor.

Comment: @DanielLenz What else would you use?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake writting the code on the site. It works now and i'm working with Python 2.7

Comment: In future, please only copy-paste code into [SO], never retype it. That way you know you are sharing exactly what you ran.

Comment: To make this faster i can only think on a solution where you split the list in equals parts and then give each part to different threads and each thread reports the maximum it found to a main thread that outputs the result when all threads are done.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'd use strings as keys, or probably a format other than a list of dicts in the first place.

Comment: @DanielLenz But what if the keys naturally are ints? Why would you make them something they're not?

Comment: @StefanPochmann It might be the right way to go in some cases, but I'd be reluctant to say that the data format here is pythonic. We'd have to know the underlying question, of course.

Comment: @DanielLenz Yeah. We don't know. And there's nothing wrong with it per se. So I don't understand why you advise against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all dictionaries in the list; iterate over each dictionary, grabbing the values.  Take `max` of that.  Use the built-in constructors to let the run-time system optimize things for you, as best it can.

In Python 2.7:

```
ddd = [{0: 0, 1: 1.4589, 4: 2.4879},
       {0: 1.4589, 1: 0, 2: 2.1547},
       {1: 2.1547, 2: 0, 3: 4.2114},
       {2: 4.2114, 3: 0},
       {0: 2.4879, 4: 0}]

def findMax(data):
    return max(val for item in data for val in item.itervalues())

print "MAX", findMax(ddd)
```

Output:

```
MAX 4.2114
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann: the iterator grabs both values for any iteration; using an underscore would be a little more clear to intermediate coders, but I used this for clarity to OP.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: thanks for the vote of confidence and the `import` catch, but I simply goofed from mental context switching.

Comment: this does create a temp list obj. if initial list is big then it will create a large list obj which is not necessary.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: `for val in item.itervalues()` returns the entry as a tuple; we want only the second element.

Comment: @StefanPochmann:  <facepalm> Maybe I've reverted to noob.  Bad day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think the one liner version is succinct without being unreadable:

```
my_list = [{0: 0, 1: 1.4589, 4: 2.4879},
           {0: 1.4589, 1: 0, 2: 2.1547},
           {1: 2.1547, 2: 0, 3: 4.2114},
           {2: 4.2114, 3: 0},
           {0: 2.4879, 4: 0}]
print(max(max(part.values()) for part in my_list))
```

Python 3 code. Use `dict.itervalues()` for Python 2.

Comment: It is slower that way. At least on python 2.7

Comment: That is entirely possible (likely?). Did you change it to use `itervalues()`? Without that change for 2.7, it will be making copies of every dictionary. Other than that, have you considered using a different language? Python can solve this problem elegantly, but it's rarely the fastest.

Comment: Yeah it’s better using dict.itervalues() but it still slower. And it’s my decision to use that langage for my final university project. I want to learn how to use python with efficiency :)

Comment: Is NumPy an option? Loading an array of values into NumPy and finding the max will happen in compiled code - raw Python couldn't compete.

Comment: Well, I am using dijkstra algorithm from networkx library which return dictionary as output. Do you think it would be faster to first convert into jumpy array before looking for the highest value ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to iterate through the list once, you could try this.

```
import sys
lo,hi = sys.maxint,-sys.maxint-1

for item in (item.values() for item in allIndices):
    for x in item:
        lo,hi = min(x,lo),max(x,hi)

print hi[0]
```